# What's wrong with this PHP script for creating MySQL tables?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, xampp, relational-database

This is the script that is supposed to install my MySQL database tables:

```
include("parameter.php");
$link = mysql_connect($host,$user,$password); 
mysql_select_db($database); 

$anfrage="DROP TABLE IF EXISTS praktikumsplatz;"; 
mysql_query($anfrage);
$anfrage="CREATE TABLE praktikumsplatz (
praktikumsplatz_id INTEGER(6) not null auto_increment, 
einrichtung VARCHAR(30), 
einrichtungort VARCHAR(30),
ansprechname VARCHAR(30), 
ansprechvorname VARCHAR(30),
ansprechmail VARCHAR(50), 
praktikumstyp VARCHAR(30), 
bezahlung VARCHAR(30), 
pbeginn DATE,
pende DATE,
beschreibung TEXT,
primary key (praktikumsplatz_id),
fulltext (einrichtung));";
mysql_query($anfrage);

$anfrage="DROP TABLE IF EXISTS studierender;"; 
mysql_query($anfrage); 
$anfrage="CREATE TABLE studierender (
matrikelnummer INTEGER(5) not null, 
sname VARCHAR(30), 
svorname VARCHAR(30),
semail VARCHAR(50), 
studiengang VARCHAR(30), 
primary key (matrikelnummer),
fulltext (sname, svorname, studiengang));";
mysql_query($anfrage);

$anfrage="DROP TABLE IF EXISTS vermittlung;"; 
mysql_query($anfrage); 
$anfrage="CREATE TABLE vermittlung (
vermittlung_id INTEGER(6) not null auto_increment, 
praktikumsplatz_id INTEGER, 
matrikelnummer INTEGER,
vermittlungsdatum DATE,
primary key (vermittlung_id));";
mysql_query($anfrage);

echo "Installation erfolgreich abgeschlossen!";
mysql_close($link);
```

Here you can see the mentioned parameter.php

```
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$password = "usbw";
$database = "test";
```

This is the error I get when executing the install script in my Browser (I use an USB stick with the USBWebserver Stack, similar to Xampp):

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in E:\USBMySQLServer\root\praktikumsboerse\install.php on line 24

This is the line this refers to, but I doubt that it's the reason for this strange behaviour:

```
$anfrage="DROP TABLE IF EXISTS studierender;";
```

Comment: some other process is reading from that table at the time you are trying to drop it.

Answer (score 1):

You got the error because your request too long processing. You can increase execution time in php.ini or using [ini_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php). But best solution for updating/support db - run scripts from console.

All migrations runs from the console. Just open console and run:

```
php my_script.php
```

You can use any tool for migrations. For example [something like this](https://phinx.org/). It will be the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

-Place this at the top of your PHP script

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
```

Comment: I changed the maximum execution time, but no change here. It will hang and the install script still is not executed properly.

Answer (score 0):

In this code first mistake is operator include. If configuration file is not exist you have to get error.

Try to use:

`require("parameter.php");`